# Regexextract text just before specific text Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, extract

I need to extract the text that comes before the text `District`

Example String:

```
9224+H63, Ban Suan, Chon Buri District, Chon Buri 20000, Thailand
```

Valid Output should be `Chon Buri District`.

I tried `=REGEXEXTRACT(K661,",\s([^\District]+")` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(K661, ",\s*([^,]*?District)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Eu29W/3).

*Details*:

- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^,]*?District)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than a comma as few as possible and then a `District` fixed string.